# What is the difference between DEBUG and NODE_DEBUG for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I notice that NODE_DEBUG are more explicit than DEBUG, but why they are 2 environnements variables for debug, and how do I decide which to choose?

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NODE_DEBUG` is used by built in [`util.debuglog`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_debuglog_section). This is used by all nodejs builtin core modules and all the third party packages that decide to use it.

`DEBUG` is used by [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module. So if you are using any package that is using this module for logging, then you need to use `DEBUG`.

So depending on which modules you are trying to debug you may need to use one of them or both.